# CSS media query does not apply to Firefox 37

Tags: css, firefox, media-queries

I was working on a website (originally designed elsewhere) adding CSS media queries to adjust the layout to make it more mobile friendly.

I had completed the work about a month ago. However, I have seen now some odd behaviour and would like to know why the following happens and how to work around it or correct it:

Some notes:

- The website is http://www.stablesathenhampark.com
- The website worked as intended on all browsers when it was completed (mid April 2015)
- The issue appears *only* on Firefox.

**The issue:**

[image]

As you can see, on Chrome the CSS realigns the menu underneath the video as intended. On Firefox it does not, staying beside the video as it should at larger browser widths. These two browsers are exactly the same page, exactly the same time, right next to each other.

I have spent a good while researching the various media queries and have found that Firefox does not appear to apply a certain media query for if  `width < 400px`

The media query which Firefox does NOT apply, but Chrome DOES:

```
@media only screen
and (max-width : 400px) {
    .outerBox {
        width:96% !important;
    }
    .topBox > object {
        width:98% !important;
        float:none !important;
        display:block !important;
        margin:0 auto !important;
    }
    .topBox > nav {
        background-color:#8FB4A2 !important;
        width:96% !important;
        text-align:center !important;
        }
    .topBox > nav a{
        display:inline-block !important;
    }
}
```

I know which media queries are and are not applied because I added a background colour identifier to the media query rules as per another post on Stack Overflow.

Now, I then researched why this was not applying, and so used Firebug to check the size of the `<body>` (and also `<html>`) element in the browser and sure enough the Firebug told me that this plugin was reading the `<body>` tag (and `<html>` tag) had a stated width of **389px**.

This website worked perfectly a month ago, so what's changed? Firefox updated itself to **version 37.0.2**. That's the only thing I can think that would effect this. No one has updated the code on the site and it was fully working when completed.

I want the website to look on Firefox like it looks on Chrome (**version 41.0.2272**). This issue only applies to Firefox. On Opera, Safari and Internet Explorer the media query rules apply correctly.

***Is there a way I can work around or otherwise fix this issue?***

Edit:
A fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/5hqvm8c7/ . The fiddle appears to work as intended viewed in the JSFiddle Environment and in Firefox browser.

Replacing the `<object>` with an `<img>` also works with another fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ow0yjmmc/1/

### Update

I have replaced the `<object>` tag with a static image, and the behaviour still remains the same, perfect everywhere except FireFox:

http://www.stablesathenhampark.com/indexNew.php

Comment: I can't tell you for sure why it worked once and then not now, but it's broken in a different way in MY firefox, and I think it has something to do with your flash object tag having an inline width declared at 700. Firefox seems to use that and ignore the media query rule.

Comment: @Quintile I have removed the base values in the HTML for width and height for the object but this still does not change the issue. I have also removed the reserve image which should apply if the video is blocked, as that also had inline sizes but this also does not change the issue.

Comment: I refreshed and while it now shows the (a plugin is required), the object is now responsive. Firefox 37.0.2 for Mac.

Comment: I am also on Firefox 37.0.2 (pc), but the site/object are not applying the media query. The `<object>` element scales perfectly but the media query still does not work for me. The menu should be underneath the video on widths < 400.

Comment: Yeah that's weird that we're getting different results. The menu is appearing below the video with my viewport set to 389px wide.

Comment: Can you recheck it, as I returned the width/height values to the html object element, so if the issue returns for you now then at least I've found what's causing it for you, and can put it down to +1 for macs!

Comment: Still working! Not sure what's happening

Comment: Hmm, well I'm pleased it does work for you. I'm still confused, but cheers for your help!

Comment: @Quintile ok one more experiment, I had also removed the image that is meant to show if the video is blocked, so re-applying that image - does it still work correctly for you? thanks!

Comment: no, the image is now 700px wide even though the viewport is set at 400px, so it's off the page.

Comment: Ok, thats caused by the "reserve" image, even though my own Firefox didn't display the media query correctly when the image was removed, it's good to know. Cheers again for your help, @Quintile

Comment: The site (and menu) behaves the same for me in Firefox 37.0.2 as it does in Chrome 42.0.2311.135. Have you cleared your cache and done a hard refresh?

Comment: @TylerH yes, yes I have, repeatedly!

Comment: Please include the minimal amount of HTML and CSS to reproduce the issue here in the post.

Comment: @TylerH Hello again, I have added a fiddle with everything that should be going on with that section of the page. The fiddle appears to work correctly in Firefox in the JSFiddle encironment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue appeared to be with using the modernizr JavaScript function, disabling this link resovled the issue.

Answer (score 0):

*1.) What mobile devices rely on Firefox (or this version for that matter). Decide if this is worth caring for a mobile optimization.* Also; Note: // The only way to fully accurately test on mobile is using the actual device.

**2.) Make sure your viewing the exact same resolution in both browsers. Some browsers don't minimize as much as others. It looks like chrome is smaller in your screenshot there, so firefox could just not be at the defined break-point yet.**

*3.) Add a unique selector to that image there and force it to take the page. If the below elements don't snap into place, add a unique wrapper and do the same to them as well.*

*Also, tip! I always prefer using between two widths to call my media queries. Could help switching to this method as it's easier to test with IMO.*

**For browser testing try using this method:**

```
/* No greater than 480px, no less than 100px */
@media (max-width:480px) and (min-width:100px) {
    .foo {
        display:none;
    }
}​
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - to reply to you: 1) this is not *just* for mobile devices but the inconsistency that something does not look as it should on one browser, at one size, I was asking if a) this was a recognised bug/glitch and b) if there was a work around for it

Comment: 2) Both browsers where clearly below the stated size for the 400px wide media query and the firebug on Firefox actually told me as much, as detailed in the question.

Comment: Also re: your media query suggestion, my media query is for sizes UPTO 400px so do I really need to set out a `(min-width:1px)` addition, I don't think this is the cause of the issue.

Comment: 3) I do not see how adding a selector will change much as the issue is that the media query rule does not apply, across the page - whereas the *CSS rules* do work, the *media rule* it is in, does not.

Comment: Try the way I'm calling the media queries... with a min-width. Some media queries ONLY are fully previewable with meta / mobile.

Comment: I have added the `min-width` rules to the media query and it has not changed the issue. (I did a hard refresh too.)

Comment: Did you remove media only, eg. @media (max-width:480px) and (min-width:100px) {

Comment: Also, on your styles -- Instead of using all % do: 'max-width: 800px; // pixels  then width: 100%; and then min-width: 320px; // lowest

Comment: That would not make sense re: `@media screen only` as all my media queries are structured with that syntax and if that was a factor then all/none of them would work.

Comment: my media query widths are always `px` rather than `%`

Comment: Your code is a mess         width:96% !important; no, i mean selector styles.

Comment: With respect, adding `!important` to declarations is used to overwrite the default values. As explained in the question the issue is established that the media query detailed in the question does not fire on Firefox, whereas it does on all other browsers. This has been established by setting different background colours on the `body{ }` element for different media queries to know which is applying when.

Comment: Selector styles should not be `px` as that is a very un-dynamic way of layout a page to look the same at 350px wide to 1500px wide.

Comment: I do appreciate your help, please don't think otherwise, but I am not seeing your reasoning for some of your suggestions.

Comment: Well, we can't do your work for you -- but just try to help you debug. Best of luck to you on this.